# Res.json is blocking my node/express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a 100mb object that I try to return with a GET request:

```
function doWork(req,res) {

  // creates a big object on a child process, then returns this big object

  res.json(bigObject); // <--- problem line
}
app.get('/dowork', doWork);
```

Even though I am creating this big object on a child process I need the main process to return it (b/c the child process doesn't have the res stream). I'm wondering what's the proper way to do this? Right now converting this big object to json is horking my server for a while. No-one can connect while it is doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't return it as an object from the child process. Instead, call `JSON.stringify` in there already, and *stream* it back to your main process. You can then hook this output stream of the child process to write to the [`res`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) by using [`.pipe()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options).

Comment: is there an example for what you're saying somewhere (I'm trying to look now). I did find though that alot of my issues are when the child process is "giving" the info back to the main thread, they both seem to hang. So I do think you have a point about streaming..

Comment: No, I just made this up :-) No references, unfortunately, and I haven't tried this. It might even be that writing to the child's output stream is blocking, and doesn't get chunked automatically at the process boundary. You might want to search for a lib that can stream JSON in that case.